# date in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, date

d = 10
m = 2
y = 2011

I would like to create an Sql Date type using the above info ?
How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @d INT = 10,
        @m INT = 2,
        @y INT = 2011

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, @d - 1, 
       DATEADD(MONTH, @m - 1, 
       DATEADD(YEAR, @y - 1, CAST('00010101' AS DATE))))
```

Answer (score 0):

if the column type is DateTime try to use the following:

```
set dateformat dmy

insert into TABLE_NAME (COL_NAME) VALUES ('10.02.2011')
```